# New RxJS subscription gets created during page hot module replacement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, rxjs, next.js

I'm importing a newed up subject from an internal NPM package into my Next.js application.

Internal NPM Package

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export const errorSubject = new Subject<{}>();
```

Next.js App

```
import { errorSubject } from '@my-package'

// Inside component's render
render() {
  errorSubject.subscribe({
    next: v => console.log(v),
  });
}
```

Everytime the Next.js hot-reloads, a new subscription is created. If I reload the pages, only 1 subscription remains.

This is causing issues because multiple callbacks are ran.

---

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqy3RPQocRw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a reference to your subscription so everytime you unmount the component you get rid of it.

```
private _subscription;


render() {
  this._subscription = errorSubject.subscribe({
    next: v => console.log(v),
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked! Thanks so much. I tried componentWillUnmount() previously but didn't keep track of the private subscription in my class